# Default range shard key mongodb

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a mongodb shard with 2 shards (let say A & B), 17GB free space each. I set _id which contains object ID as shard key.

Below are commands used to set db and collection.

```
sh.enableSharding("testShard");
sh.shardCollection("testShard.shardedCollection", {_id:1});
```

Then I tried to fire 4,000,000 insert queries to mongos server. I execute script below 4 times.

```
for(var i=0; i<1000000; i++){
  db.shardedCollection.insert({x:i});
}
```

Using _id as shard key, as per my understanding, 4000000 document as mentioned will fit in 1 shard and all insert will happens in A shard only.

However, the result was not as I expected, it is ~1,3 million documents inserted in A shard, another ~2,7 million documents inserted in B shard.

Why did it happen? Are something missing in shard coll setting commands? Or my understanding is wrong, maybe there is something like default range shard key in mongodb?

It will be very helpful if someone can share the behavior of default range shard key (without tag aware).

Below is sh.status() result

```
  shard key: { "_id" : 1 }
  chunks:
    B  5
    A  5
  { "_id" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c703398c7efdea6037cbc") } on : B Timestamp(6, 0) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c703398c7efdea6037cbc") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c703498c7efdea603bfe3") } on : A Timestamp(6, 1) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c703498c7efdea603bfe3") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c704398c7efdea605d818") } on : A Timestamp(3, 0) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c704398c7efdea605d818") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c705298c7efdea607f04e") } on : A Timestamp(4, 0) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c705298c7efdea607f04e") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c707098c7efdea60c20ba") } on : B Timestamp(5, 1) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c707098c7efdea60c20ba") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c7144319c0dbee096f7d6") } on : B Timestamp(2, 4) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c7144319c0dbee096f7d6") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540c7183319c0dbee09f58ad") } on : B Timestamp(2, 6) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540c7183319c0dbee09f58ad") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540eb15ddace5b39fbc32239") } on : B Timestamp(4, 2) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540eb15ddace5b39fbc32239") } -->> { "_id" : ObjectId("540eb192dace5b39fbca8a84") } on : A Timestamp(5, 2) 
  { "_id" : ObjectId("540eb192dace5b39fbca8a84") } -->> { "_id" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : A Timestamp(5, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah you are right it should have gone to a single shard. But while there is insertions going on a single shard, the balancer would be also balancing the shards and moving chunks to other shards.

Having said that, what you should do is stop/disable the balancer by invoking the below command from your mongos.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/sh.disableBalancing/#sh.disableBalancing

```
sh.disableBalancing(namespace)
//namespace     string  The namespace of the collection.
```

Once done, kick off your inserts and see where all the inserts are heading to.

For _id field sharding you could also look here:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/sharding/#can-you-shard-on-the-id-field

```
Be aware that ObjectId() values, which are the default value of the _id field, 
increment as a timestamp. As a result, when used as a shard key, all new documents
inserted into the collection will initially belong to the same chunk on a single 
shard. Although the system will eventually divide this chunk and migrate its contents 
to distribute data more evenly, at any moment the cluster can only direct insert 
operations at a single shard. This can limit the throughput of inserts. If most of 
your write operations are updates, this limitation should not impact your performance. 
However, if you have a high insert volume, this may be a limitation.
```

Comment: when balancer is disabled, if first shard is full, will it continue writing documents to the next shard?

Comment: I think NO. For mongos to write to any specific shard, that particular chunk range needs to be present in that shard. Once you disable the balancer you will not have any chunks to the next shard. To make it possible you will have to split and move the chunk to the other shard manually and then mongos would start putting data into the other shard.

Answer (score 6):

As @LalitAgarwal already pointed out, ObjectIds make a bad shard key by default. However, if you don't really care on which shard your data lives and only want to have the write operations and the chunks distributed evenly among you shards, this is quite easy to acquire:

```
db.shardedCollection.ensureIndex({_id:"hashed"});
sh.enableSharding("testShard");
sh.shardCollection("testShard.shardedCollection", {_id:"hashed"});
```

However, this comes with some (often negligible) drawbacks:

1. You have an additional index for the sole purpose of sharding and no other use cases
2. This index will eat some RAM, a precious ressource on high load production nodes
3. This artificial index will need write operations during insertions

A way better approach is to find a non-artificial shard key. Please read [Considerations for Selecting Shard Keys](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/choose-a-shard-key/) for details. In short:

1. Find a field or combination of fields which unambiguously identify each document **and** (in combination) greatly differ from each other. Ideally, those should be fields you query for anyway.
2. Use this field or combination of fields as your _id. Since an index is needed on the _id field anyway, and you query for those fields, you got rid of unneeded index(es).
3. Use the selected _id field as your shard key.

Comment: I will read the document sequentially by objectId. Hence I think it is a good idea to sacrifice write at 1 shard but when I want to read sequentially it will be localized at 1 shard as well.

Comment: No, it won't, since the balancer will kick in sooner or later. ;)